# Fetch specific array elements from a array element within another array field in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, bson

My document structure is as below.

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-08-27T06:00:00.000+05:30"),
        "category" : "marketing"
    },
    "leveldata" : [ 
        {
            "level" : "manager",
            "volume" : [ 
                "45", 
                "145", 
                "2145"
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "level" : "engineer",
            "volume" : [ 
                "2145"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**"leveldata.volume"** embedded array document field can have around 60 elements in it.

In this case, "**leveldata**" is an array document.

And "**volume**" is another array field inside "**leveldata**".

We have a requirement to fetch specific elements from the "volume" array field.

For example, elements from specific positions, For Example, position **1-5** within the array element "**volume**".

Also, we have used positional operator to fetch the specific array element in this case based on **"leveldata.level"** field.

I tried using the **$slice** operator. But, it seems to work only with arrays not with array inside array fields, as that
is the case in my scenario.

We can do it from the application layer, but that would mean loading the entire the array element from mongo db to memory and
then fetching the desired elements. We want to avoid doing that and fetch it directly from mongodb.

The below query is what I had used to fetch the elements as required.

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').find(
{
    "_id" : {
          "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-08-26T18:00:00.000-06:30"),
          "category" : "sales"
    }
   ,
    "leveldata.level":"manager"
}, 
{
   "leveldata.$.volume": { $slice: [ 1, 5 ] }
}
)
```

Can you please let us know your suggestions on how to address this issue.

Thanks,

mongouser

Answer (score 0):

Well yes you can use `$slice` to get that data like

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').find({"leveldata.level":"manager"} , { "leveldata.volume" : { $slice : [3 , 1] } } )
```

Comment: Thanks. The  query, fetches data for both the "levels" "engineer" and "manager". It should select only the element for which the "level" field matches the value "manager". That is the reason, I have used positional operator in the query as "leveldata.$.volume".